# Button width auto expand?

Tags: css, button

I have a button in another div that is 980px long. The problem is that I want the button to autoexpand depending on the text that I put in but I don't know how do do it because what ever I do it expands to 980px or it doesn't autoexpand based on the text.

This is my CSS code for my button:

```
.button_small_menu {
        color: #fff;
        font: 10px/1 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 80px;
        float: right; }
    .button_small_menu:hover {
        background-color: #4781b3;
        cursor: pointer; }
```

HTML-code:

```
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="button_small_menu">Logout</div>
    </div>
```

CSS for "header-content":

```
.header-content {
    width:980px;
    margin:auto; }
```

Comment: Can you post the html code as well

Comment: Added HTML code + CSS for the 980px box.

Comment: What do you mean "depending on the text"? Is the text size limited in some way?

Comment: Well, I ment that the button width should be based on the text lenght, there is no text size limit, the lenght will however not be longer than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery. First calculate the length of the text by this code

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};
```

And after that change the width of the button with that code

```
$('.selector').width(yourwidth);
```